# Small white square on screen

Tags: windows-10, display

I have recently noticed a small white square on the bottom right of my laptop screen. I have absolutely no idea what that is or how to take it off. Here is a print screen.

[image]

This little white square is not on the top of everything on the screen. If, say, I click on the notifications button, we do not see the square

[image]

Any idea of what that is? Or how to get rid of it?

If it is relevant, on the tray I have:

- CCleaner
- Acer Care Center
- GeForce 920M
- Avast
- NVidia GeForce Experience
- Avast SecureLine
- Drive File Stream

My computer is an Acer Aspire E15 with Windows 10, 64 bits.

Answer (score 3):

Use a process manager app which lets you directly point at a window. For example: Process Hacker, or SysInternals ProcExp – both have a toolbar button that you can drag.

[image: ProcExp screenshot]

Doing so should select the corresponding process in the list. From there you can kill it, or investigate why it's showing up like that. (It might be one of your "tray apps" being slightly buggy and accidentally showing a window that was meant to be event-only.)

Comment: interestingly, in my case this selects the whole desktop and points to explorer.exe, I guess it's a bug with Windows Explorer